# Percentage Change with new column for increased data set in R

Tags: r, dataframe, percentage

I have the below data set with different fruit and Veg Mix and week on week their quantity would like to get percentage change for each data column.

The total is already mentioned below for each column.

How do I get the percentage change from each column in r ?The concern is that how do I do week on week % change as the data will be update WOW so Instead of manual I would like to automatically add a a new column at the end or a new data set with % change every time the data is updated.

```
Type      X22        X23         X24          X25    x26
Apple    10,000      20,000      30,000      40,000  ...
Banana   555          345         456         567    ... 
Mango    123          344         456        1,189   ... 
Onion    77,686      9,995       8,899        533    ... 
Tomato   233          444         566        6,788   ... 
Beans    123          556        4,566         777   ...
Total    88,720      31,684      44,943      49,854
```

Desired Output

```
 Type    X22    X23      X24     x25    x26
Apple   11.27%  63.12%  66.75%  80.23%  ...
Banana  0.63%   1.09%   1.01%   1.14%   ... 
Mango   0.14%   1.09%   1.01%   2.38%   ...
Onion   87.56%  31.55%  19.80%  1.07%   ... 
Tomato  0.26%   1.40%   1.26%   13.62%  ...
Beans   0.14%   1.75%   10.16%  1.56%   ...
Total   100.00% 100.00% 100.00% 100.00% ....
```

Comment: could you provide a `?dput` of your data so we can better help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `df` is your original dataframe, the following should do (assuming all your numeric columns are in `numeric` format.

```
df_percentage <- cbind(df[1], 
                       data.frame(lapply(df[2:ncol(df)], 
                                         function(x) paste0(format(round(x / x[length(x)], 2), nsmall = 2), "%"))))
```

Comment: Can you let me know if it is an integer is there a way out?

Comment: @ArkadeepPaulChoudhury What is an integer?

Comment: the  X22 in this case

Comment: It should still work, my comment about the columns type was meant to ensure that the numerical ones where formatted correctly and not as a character type, like the "Type" column.